# How to use "be : was or were " for as if/as though ( the unreal information in the present)

Tags: grammar, tense, plural-forms, singular, sentence

For As if/As though, if the sentence expresses the information which is unreal in the present, we  use "past subjunctive"  and to be : were for all the subjects? Is it correct or incorrect?

For example:
He acts as though he were rich. ( But he is not rich).
--> We use "were" for all the subjects in this case or we can use "was" for singular subject and "were" for plural subject?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive is always *were.*

> He acts as though he were rich.
>
> (I) wish you were here (traditional message on holiday postcards).
>
> I wish I were taller. (This is the correct version, though many people would use *I wish I was* in informal speech.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.